# LoginActivty Template for Android Studios (the most current version) Need to verify username and password before going on to next activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, authentication

Here is my problem:

I am currently using the LoginActivity template in android studio to log users into our app. The activity is designed quite well - almost too well. What I mean by this is that there are multiple java files dedicated to different functionalities and they all meet up at the end which would be the actual LoginActivity.

The thing I want to add into the LoginActivity template is to check the username and password that the user has entered and see if it matches to any usernames and passwords within our database (database is made with SQL Lite). As you can already assume: if what the user entered matches exactly to what is in the database then the user successfully logs in and the app starts a new activity.

I have no idea how to do this because as I stated earlier there are so many java files for this one activity and each folder has a different functionality. I have looked all over the internet and at different videos but they are all outdated. I am hoping somebody has messed around a bit with the current LoginActivity template that AndroidStudio has and can help me solve where I need to place the logic and what goes where.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read up on MVVM architecture pattern first since the new template made use of mvvm pattern and is quite a broad subject. Else just go back to basic create a simple ui with 2 edittext and 1 button and validate from there.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple, **not very secure login**, using just 3 files *(edit 2 existing and 1 new)*, derived from the Empty Activity template.

1. the layout (**activity_main.xml**),
2. the activity (**MainActivity.java**) and
3. the subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper aka the database helper (**DatabaseHelper.java**)

When run from a fresh install (empty user table (so also a rerun if no user was registered)) it prompts to register a new user as per :-

[image]

When a new user is registered or if a user exists it prompts for the user login details (until valid use details are input) :-

[image]

Finally when a valid user is provided then the prompts and button are removed and other data is displayed :-

[image]

## Code

### MainActivity.java (with some instructions)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /* Step 1 - Create DatabaseHelper for the Database */
    /* Create new class DatabaseHelper with SQLiteOpenHelper as the super class */
    /* Click Select Overrides Dialog and click SQLiteOpenHelper (shorter of the 2) */
    /* Click onCreate and also onUpgrade */
    /* EDIT DatabaseHelper.java */

    /* Step 3 - Amend activity_main.xml */

    /* Step 4 - Declare the DatabaseHelper and Views*/

    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    EditText mUsername,mUserPassword;
    TextView mMessage,mSomethingToDisplay;
    Button mPerformAction;
    String loggedInUser = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //* Step 5. instantiate Views and DBHelper
        mUsername = this.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        mUserPassword = this.findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
        mMessage = this.findViewById(R.id.message);
        mSomethingToDisplay = this.findViewById(R.id.somethingToDisplay);
        mPerformAction = this.findViewById(R.id.performAction);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //* Step 9. see what to do
        if (!mDBHelper.isThereUsers() && loggedInUser.length() < 1) {
            registerNewUser();
        } else {
            loginUser();
        }
    }

    /* Step 7.  Registering a new User*/
    private void registerNewUser() {
        mMessage.setText("Requesting to Register a New user. Enter details and click REGISTER NEW USER.");
        mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mUsername.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mUserPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPerformAction.setText("REGISTER NEW USER");
        mPerformAction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPerformAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUsername.getText().toString().length() < 1 || mUserPassword.getText().toString().length() < 1 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You must enter a Username and Password (neither can be blank).",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    registerNewUser();
                } else {
                    if (mDBHelper.addUser(mUsername.getText().toString(),mUserPassword.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                        loginUser();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /* Step 8. User Login */
    private void loginUser() {
        mMessage.setText("Requesting to Login. Enter details and click LOGIN");
        mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mUsername.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mUsername.setText("");
        mUserPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mUserPassword.setText("");
        mPerformAction.setText("LOGIN");
        mPerformAction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPerformAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUsername.getText().toString().length() < 1 || mUserPassword.getText().toString().length() < 1 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"You must enter a Username and Password (neither can be blank).",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loginUser();
                }
                if (mDBHelper.isUserValid(mUsername.getText().toString(),mUserPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    loggedInUser = mUsername.getText().toString();
                    mMessage.setText("Loggined in as User >" + loggedInUser);
                    mMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mUsername.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mUserPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mPerformAction.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSomethingToDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        >
    </TextView>

    <!-- 1. ADD EditText for User Name -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
    </EditText>
    <!-- 2. Add EditText for UserPassword -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/performAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
    </Button>

    <!-- Add soemthing else to only be displayed when logged in -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/somethingToDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Congratulations you have logged in."
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### DatabaseHelper.java :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb"; /* 1. The database name  ADDED*/
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; /* 2. The database version number ADDED*/

    public static final String TABLE_USER = "user"; /*3. The table for the user ADDED*/
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; /* 4. Universal _id Column */
    public static final String COL_USER_USERNAME = "userName"; /* 5. column for the user's name (email?) ADDED*/
    public static final String COL_USER_PASSWORD = "password"; /* 6. column for the password (not very secure) ADDED*/
    public static final String COL_USER_SALT = "usersalt"; /*7. column for salt (for more secure) OPTIONAL */
    public static final String COL_USER_HASH = "userhash"; /*8. column for hash (for more secure) OPTIONAL */

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    /* WAS
    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    */
    /* 10. Simpler DatabaseHelper constructor - only needs the Context */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); /* will force open and therefore run onCreate if need be */
    }

    // 11.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /* 11. ADDED the following code block */
        String createUserTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USER +
                "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_USER_USERNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +
                COL_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
                COL_USER_SALT + " TEXT," +
                COL_USER_HASH + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(createUserTableSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /* 12. Method to allow user to be added to the user table*/
    /* will return the id of the user 1 or greater if added OK, else -1 */
    public long addUser(String userName, String userPassword) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_USER_USERNAME,userName);
        cv.put(COL_USER_PASSWORD,userPassword);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_USER,null,cv);
    }

    //13. Method to check if user credentials match user in the database */
    public boolean isUserValid(String userName, String userPassword) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = COL_USER_USERNAME + "=? AND " + COL_USER_PASSWORD + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{userName,userPassword};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TABLE_USER,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = true;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean isThereUsers() {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB,TABLE_USER) > 0;
    }
}
```